# Call react hooks inside event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, fetch

I need to re-fetching data if i click some button, but when i call hook inside click handler i get following error

```
const Menus = ({ menus, title }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const { data: cartItems } = useFetch(API_URL + 'cart');
  }
}
```

> src\components\Menus.js | Line 26:13:  React Hook "useFetch" is called in function "handleMenu" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React hooks can't be used inside a pure JavaScript function. It will break the rules of hooks. Hooks can only be used in React function components. A function returning ReactElement will be treated as a React function component instead of a normal function in JS.

You should return the data and a data fetch function in the `useFetch` hook. So that you can use the data fetch function later.

E.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';
const api = {
  async getCartItems() {
    return ['apple', 'banana'];
  },
};

function useFetch(url: string) {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState<string[]>([]);
  
  // fetch data later use this function.
  const getCartItems = useCallback(() => {
    return api.getCartItems().then((res) => {
      setCartItems(res);
    });
  }, [url]);
 
  // fetch data when component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    getCartItems();
  }, [url]);

  return { data: cartItems, getCartItems };
}

const Menus = () => {
  const { data: cartItems, getCartItems } = useFetch(API_URL + 'cart');
  const handleClick = () => {
    getCartItems();
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <ul>
        {cartItems.map((item, i) => {
          return <li key={i}>{item}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error mentions, the issue violates the rules of hooks (`react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`)
More information can be found here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

You can only use hooks in the top level of functional components but the `handleClick()` function would put the hook at the second level rather than the top level.